# "You can only install one version of a package" error when upgrading from 2.2.6 to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I am trying to upgrade from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.4.3. This is what I have done so far:

```
php composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update --> That worked without errors
```

Now I just ran

```
composer update
```

which resultet in: https://pastebin.com/CyiF2b6E

I tried with `php composer update --with-all-dependencies` and `php composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`, its always the same message.

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recent the Magento 2.2.1 to 2.4.3 upgrade with success and make sure prepare your composer.json file with below required module of the magento core.

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3 --no-update

composer update

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "~2.15.1",
        "amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin": "5.9.1",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.2",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
        "symfony/config": "^4.2",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.0",
        "laminas/laminas-serializer": "^2.12"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.0.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3"
    },
```

After successfully upgrade then run below command.

```
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```

Comment: Thanks for the accept the answer and upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggests that `peridot-php/peridot` package v1.16 that you require only works with `symfony/console` in version `~2.0`, which is equivalent to any 2.x version and thus incompatible with 3.x version of `symfony/console` which Laravel requires.

First version of `peridot-php/peridot` that supports `symfony/console` 3.x is 1.18.1, so you need to bump your dependency to that version to support Symfony Console 3.x properly.